# Best way to reverse deploy an asp.net mvc web application which is not precompiled

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012

I have a Visual Studio 2012, MVC 3, asp.net 4.5, c#, razor web application.

The original application is a 2 project solution with 1 project being the Data layer and the other the web application. When deployed the data layer is represented as a dll.

All Controllers and Views are still in "source" format on the deployed "test" platform, since I have not precompiled the code before deploying.

I have ftped the whole site back to my dev server into a seperate area.

I did try and open this downloaded application as a project and also a website, but got some reference errors.

I do appreciate this is a non ideal state of affairs, and this codebase should be represented as a previous version in source control. However for a number of reason, we need to do this, mainly because we did not do a branch. One lives and learns.

What should be the best way to open this site in Visual Studio to work on it. Obviously I will only have the one project now, as the data project is just another DLL? I will add this fix back to my main codebase, and recommit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Copy the project file from the working project to your backup of the test server.

Comment: Now complaining that "View" as in "return View" cannot be resolved. Also "ViewBag", so I guess I have lost a reference from MVC ?

Comment: Ended up using Subversion to recover a previous version which worked fine with some tweaks.